# Navigate through pages in mvvm in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have been searching on how to navigate through the pages in Silverlight 4 (navigation application) when I have implemented MVVM pattern. But nothing I found satisfied me.

I have a main page which has frame in it. In that frame I load home page which does simple URI mapping. But now I want to go to New Page on button's click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article (http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html) written by Jeremy Likness.

He is using Prism and the Navigation framework and it's a good article to get you going with it. It's also not hard to take the sample he provides and apply some MVVM principals to it.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a PageConductor, as introduced by John Papa and improved upon in MEFedMvmm, I think is the most elegant solution.

http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/MEFing-up-John-Papae28099s-MVVM-code-from-Firestarter.aspx